# How to get 3 days back of current date and should not be weekends

Tags: c#

How can I get 3 days back of current date and should not fall on weekends (Sat/Sun)

Let's say if date i select date as 03/28/2017. It should display date as 03/23/2017. It should not take sat/sun.

```
dto.ProcessEndDate.AddDays(-3);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be displayed 03/24/2017 (Friday), 25th is Saturday?

Comment: Yea you are right

Comment: The question is unclear. Suppose you said go back seven days from 3/28/2017.  Should that be 3/21/2017, because 3/21/2017 is not a weekend?  Or should it be 3/17/2017 because that is 7 business days before 3/21/2017?  What if you say "go back zero days", but today is a saturday; does that produce Saturday, or the previous Friday?  **Write a clear specification that describes all the possible inputs and desired outputs**, and you will find it is surprisingly easy to write a program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code assumes that if new date falls on a weekend, it will instead return the Friday before.

```
public static DateTime GetDateExcludeWeekends(DateTime date, int index)
{
    var newDate = date.AddDays(-index);

    if(newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        return newDate.AddDays(-2);
    }

    if(newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        return newDate.AddDays(-1);
    }

    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

You can tweak the logic, but the main thing is to look at the `DayOfWeek` enum property of the `DateTime` class.